# US DS-160 countries/regions within the last five years - should I include airside?

Tags: us-visa

Indian citizen, for the purpose of filling form DS-160 for US B1/B2 visa and the question "Have you traveled to any countries/regions within the last five years".

The only place I've been outside India is the London Heathrow airport about 2 years back but I stayed airside only as I missed connecting flight so had to come back to India. Does this count towards countries visited in the last 5 years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, list it.  Maybe they don't care to know about this, but if they do, and you don't include it, you run the risk of being found deceptive.

If they don't care about it, and you tell them, they'll ignore it (do mention that you never passed passport control because you missed your connection and had to turn around).

Answer (score 1):

You have to go through the passport control of UK to claim that you have been to UK. Connections and not leaving the airport doesn't matter.

In your case, make sure you explain this situation in the extra information section. As they will see the Indian entry and exit stamps and will be very suspicious, if unexplained.

Comment: Can you provide sources that "not leaving the airport doesn't matter," and that they'll "be very suspicious"?

Comment: To expand on my comment - I'm not arguing your answer, I'm saying it needs to be backed up.

Answer (score -2):

You are mixing travel & visit.

The question asks for "travel" (which is defined as: go from one place to another) -  you did travel to the UK.

If the question had said "visit" then it would depend on whether you passed immigration at Heathrow, sounds like you didn't, and remained as a traveller in-transit.

Comment: I don't think this counts in his form. As he didn't enter the UK, this doesn't matter.

Comment: Would you include flying over a country as traveling to that country? As I did travel from one place (my home nation) to 30000 feet above the land of about a dozen countries.

Comment: I believe this is where legal definitions come into play and AFAIK, the airside of ain termination terminal is not part of the country.

Comment: @HarshilSharma Well, legally it is, but transiting is usually not considered *entering* the country.

Comment: The plot thickens as the question is “_Have you traveled…_” and then “_Provide a list of countries/regions visited_”.  I think I wouldn’t count it, unless you had a visa. Not sure what I would do in the case of a DATV though.

Comment: @HarshilSharma the international airside portion of an airport is an area with special status for the purpose of customs and immigration laws, but it is still an integral part of the country's territory subject to the country's sovereignty in general (and, in particular, to all of the country's laws other than certain customs and immigration provisions).